# Disabling dragging on Bootstrap nav-tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap nav-tabs are draggable (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksY9x/4/)). If you click on the page title, you get a draggable box which contains the page title. Nothing else drags - just the title.

This doesn't look good, but isn't a problem until you put a close icon after the page title. I'm trying to give this icon the same behaviour as a normal tabbed browser close icon: in other words, if you click on the icon, but change your mind about closing the tab, you would normally just drag away. This doesn't work in BS, because you just drag away the tab title instead, and the icon remains in its selected state. Note that this has got nothing to do with the draggability or otherwise of the icon itself: the tab title drags even with no icon (see the fiddle).

So, any ideas on how to turn off dragging of the tab title in BS?

Here's some CSS for the icon to stop SO complaining that I haven't posted any code:

```
.closeIcon1 {
  width : 16px; height : 16px; float : right; margin : 2px -10px 0 4px;
  background : url('icons/close1.png') 0 0;
}
.closeIcon1:hover  { background-position: -48px 0px }
.closeIcon1:active { background-position: -16px 0px }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interaction between unselectable and undraggable in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661339/interaction-between-unselectable-and-undraggable-in-firefox)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; they're two different questions, both asked by myself. However, the fix required to turn off general dragging in Firefox (answered in the other question) is also sufficient to turn off dragging of Bootstrap nav-tabs.

Comment: I'm also have same issue and need help. Did you find something?

Comment: I did, and posted an answer, but it was deleted (presumably because it referenced another SO post). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661339/interaction-between-unselectable-and-undraggable-in-firefox